# Nginx place a prefix in my url

Tags: nginx

I'm pretty new to this nginx world, so I want to know how do I put a prefix into my url, I tried somethings that I found here but didn't work.

With my current setup I have a url like this localhost/bar and I want to put the foo prefix into, like this localhost/foo/bar

```
location /bar{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

    }
```

How do I put the foo into this configuration, can you guys help me?

Comment: You want rewrite your request from `localhost/bar` to `localhost/foo/bar`?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `return` directive and the `$request_uri` variable, like this:

```
location / {
    return 301 https://$host/foo$request_uri;
}

location /foo {
    alias /var/www/foo;
}
```

Make sure to declare the location for `/foo`. If you only want to rewrite `/bar` just set the location to `/bar` instead of just `/`, like this:

```
location /bar {
    return 301 https://$host/foo$request_uri;
}

location /foo {
    alias /var/www/foo;
}
```

Comment: With your configuration, when user visits `http://example.com/foo`, nginx tries to fetch the file from `/var/www/foo/foo`. Remember that nginx appends the URI in `location` to end of path specified in `root`.

Comment: He changed it from `root` to `alias`, which is correct.